# Programming language grammars

Tags: parsing, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

Lets say I have the following grammar

```
program = mul
mul = add {"*" add}
add = NUM {"+" NUM}
```

and the following input

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

now normally I would assume that that input would give 7, because of BIDMAS (do the multiplication first, then the addition), but after reading up on recursive descent parsers I am confused whether this would output

A.

```
(1 + 2) * 3 = 9
```

or B.

```
1 + (2 * 3) = 7
```

I want the parser to do B because that is how maths is generally done, so is the grammar I have created correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a parser won't do anything on its own, it will just produce an abstract syntax tree (AST). I believe to fully implement the mathematics order of operations you need to expand the grammar a bit. In that short example I'd expect it (unless I misunderstand this particular syntax) for it to throw an error, as you define two binary operations and pass three numbers. `1 + 2 * 3 + 4` seems like more sensible test input, and yes, it would work completely wrong (it would tell you you have an expression that consists of multiplication of two additions): `mul(add(1,2),add(3,4))`

An inverted example *might* work:

```
program = add
mul = NUM {"*" NUM}
add = mul {"+" mul}
```

I would expect it to parse `1 * 2 + 3 * 4` into `add(mul(1,2),mul(3,4))`. However, as you can see, I had to change the input, as again: you are expecting very rigid thing as an input.

Try to practice with some abstract grammars - creating specific patterns of "p" and "q" (or any other characters), to get more used to quite backward way of thinking required when working with parsers/lexers.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found that no, this is not the correct grammar. The grammar should be

```
program = add
add = mul {"+" mul}
mul = NUM {"*" NUM}
```

this way it will always add together multiplications, not multiply additions.